# How to style API to show details under correct player

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I am trying to style a webpage that has details and images of football players, however, their names and age does not go underneath the player.

Below I am pasting my code and an image of what is happening at the moment.

HTML:

```
<div class="squad-list">
        <h2 class="squad-goalkeepers-heading"></h2>
        <ul class="squad-list__players">
          <li  id="goalkeepers">
            <div class="squad-list__item-link">
              <div id="image" class="image"></div>
              <div id="details" class="details">
                <div class="r">
                  <p class="name"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="r">
                  <p class="age"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var apiKey = '<API_KEY_HERE>';
var host = 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com';
var playersResponse = null;
var playerData = null;

function requestEnglandSquad() {
  fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/players?team=10&season=2020', {
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': apiKey,
      'x-rapidapi-host': host
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Data: ', data);

    playersResponse = data.response;
    playersResponse.forEach(inputPlayers);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
}

function inputPlayers(data) {
  playerData = data.player;

  var goalkeepers = document.querySelector("#goalkeepers");
  var goalkeepersImage = document.querySelector("#goalkeeperImage");
  var goalkeepersName = document.querySelector(".name");
  var goalkeepersAge = document.querySelector(".age");
  
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  var name = document.createElement("p");
  var age = document.createElement("p");

  if (playerData.id == 2) {
    image.src = playerData.photo;
    image.classList.add("player-image");
    image.alt = "Image of " + playerData.name;
    goalkeepersImage.appendChild(image);

    name.textContent = playerData.name;
    name.classList.add("player-name");
    goalkeepersName.appendChild(name);

    age.textContent = "Age: " + playerData.age;
    age.classList.add("player-age");
    goalkeepersAge.appendChild(age);
  }

  if (playerData.id == 3) {
    image.src = playerData.photo;
    image.classList.add("player-image");
    image.alt = "Image of " + playerData.name;
    goalkeepersImage.appendChild(image);

    name.textContent = playerData.name;
    name.classList.add("player-name");
    goalkeepersName.appendChild(name);

    age.textContent = "Age: " + playerData.age;
    age.classList.add("player-age");
    goalkeepersAge.appendChild(age);
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.squad-list {
  background-color: #cfdae8;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-right: -1.5rem;
}

.squad-list__players {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: visible;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.squad-list__item-link:before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 0;
}

.squad-list__item-link {
background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.squad-list__item-link:after {
    height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.image {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 98%;
    position: relative;
}

.details {
      align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #212e65;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.details .r {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is an image of what is happening:
[image]

As you can see the names are showing underneath each other and the same for the age. But, I want to see J.Butland Age:28 under each other and J.Pickford Age:27 under each other.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a template engine like [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars) to render each player. I removed a bunch of unnecessary things to reduce the clutter.

Also, avoid reusing IDs whenever possible; try to use a class instead.

**Note:** Make sure you supply a valid API key to run the example below.

```js
var apiKey = '<API_KEY_HERE>';
var host = 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com';

var playerInfoTemplate = document.querySelector('#player-info').innerHTML;
var renderPlayerInfo = Handlebars.compile(playerInfoTemplate);

function requestSquad(team, season) {
  fetch(`https://${host}/v3/players?team=${team}&season=${season}`, {
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': apiKey,
      'x-rapidapi-host': host
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => data.response.forEach(inputPlayers))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
}

function requestEnglandSquad() {
  requestSquad(10, 2020);
}

function inputPlayers(data) {
  var players = document.querySelector(".squad-list__players");
  var playerHtml = renderPlayerInfo(data.player);
  players.append(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(playerHtml));
}

requestEnglandSquad();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.squad-heading {
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 1.33em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.33em;
}

.squad-list {
  background-color: #cfdae8;
}

.squad-list__players {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
}

.squad-list__item-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.125em;
  border: thin solid #212e65;
}

.player-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #212e65;
}

.player-details .r {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
}

.player-details .r p {
  margin: 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div class="squad-list">
  <div class="squad-heading">Squad</div>
  <ul class="squad-list__players"></ul>
</div>

<script id="player-info" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="squad-list__item-link">
    <div class="player-image-wrapper">
      <image src="{{photo}}" class="player-image" alt="Image of {{name}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="player-details">
      <div class="r">
        <p class="player-name"><strong>{{name}}</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="r">
        <p class="player-age">Age: {{age}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```